# how to get count of values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table user_places like this:

```
user_id  recorded_date  place_visited
2        2016-04-05     NY
2        2016-04-07     UK
2        2016-04-08     UK
2        2016-04-08     UK
3        2016-04-08     AUS
3        2016-04-09     AUS
2        2016-04-15     NY
```

I am trying to get the latest recorded_date of user and name of the place that he has visited the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is not too large, then you can use this trick in MySQL:

```
select user_id, max(dte),
       substring_index(group_concat(place_visited order by cnt desc), ',', 1)
from (select user_id, place_visited, count(*) as cnt, max(recorded_date) as dte
      from user_places
      group by user_id, place_visited
     ) upv
group by user_id;
```

Comment: table size is more than 70k users. Would it work with that?

Comment: Thanks @gordon it works very well. I am just curious my db would grow gradually upto 150k in couple of months will this be working fine then also?

Comment: @Lannister . . . This will work well on a 150k rows.  It might take a few seconds, but not very long.

Comment: @thanks gordon for response. Your query is very helpful. I am trying to get the name of place_visited at his latest recorded_date within this query.